# build Socks5 Poxy for my team

Tags: proxy, socks

I have been tasked to setup/build a socks5 proxy for my team. I have been googling but have not the answer I am looking for.

Requirement - We have a certain application which needs to fetch plugins/hooks from the internet.

I have successful setup Squid HTTP/HTTPS web proxy, but I need socks5 proxy in particular. I would greatly appreciate if someone helps me to find my way.

1) Is there any Enterprise version of socks5 proxy?
2) Are there any trustworthy opensource Socks5 Poxy from which I can build on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Nord VPN, they provide socks5 proxy. There are lot more open source - like shadowsocks.

Comment: Thanks, Nazia Jahan Trisha..! 
I will check and come back on this.